# How to convert MySQL blob to base64?

Tags: mysql, base64, blob

Description of the issue:
I have an Insert script contains the binary data (image file) which used to be stored in Mysql DB as a blob, and the requirement is to convert the blob data to base64 and store it in SQL Server. I tried inserting the blob data directly to SQL Server as Image and varbinary data type and converted them to base64, however, both methods failed to display the image on the web.

I tried exporting the image file from Mysql db and try to view it, but the format looks invalid.

I'm not sure what format the image file stored in Mysql DB and its hard to decode. Can anyone help me?

Sample file:

0xa15b8a9e56c2a7f9b56c4015a0eaf6abaf9f39575c028b39ffea32c35dad471522babf9f5abfeaea7eafaebafadf2d596

Comment: which language are you using and which steps did you take to put the image into the database. basically use php c# or what ever you like to get the data and convert it

Comment: FWIW, `image`and `varbinary` are binary column types. Base64 is precisely plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the problem?  MariaDB BLOB?  SQL Server?  Displaying Base64 as an image?  Something else?

Here are some tips:

- In MariaDB (at least) you can use `UNHEX(some 8-bit data)` as the expression to insert into a `BLOB` column.
- In MariaDB (at least) you can use `BASE64(some 8-bit data)` to produce a *text* string that could be put into either `TEXT` or `BLOB`.
- To display Base64 as an image in a `<img>` in HTML, you need to say that it is encoded that way.  (The details are a bit obscure, but it works, and the string is part of the html.)
- To display an image (from any of many locations), you need a *separate* program that runs in the web server, has the suitable "Header" and writes the binary (not Base64) bytes of the image.  In this case, use, or example, `<img src=foo.php?...>` where `foo.php` uses its paramters (`$_GET`) to fetch the image (and, if neccesary, convert *from* Base64), then echo the Header the the image type and the binary of the image.